# how to create a comma separated string from an array of query reults in php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have a query which returns an array of values. My task is to convert this results as comma separated values like:

`value1,value2....valuen`

I tried using explode and implode.. But it didnt worked. May be am not using it in the proper way..Here's my code:

Query

```
    $this->db->select("product_name")
    ->from('sale_items')
    ->where('sale_items.sale_id',4221);
    $q1 = $this->db->get();
    if ($q1->num_rows() > 0) {
     foreach (($q1->result()) as $row1) {
    $prdtarray[] = explode(",", $row1->product_name);
    $data1[] = $row1;
    }
    echo print_r($prdtarray);
    $product=implode(',',$prdtarray); 
    echo $product ;
```

The result is:

`$prdtarray`
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Insole Premium Shore 30 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => G Diabetic Premium closed Sandal Black size 09 ) ) 1

`$product`

```
Array,Array
```

My expected result is :

```
    (  Insole Premium Shore 30 ,G Diabetic Premium closed Sandal Black size 09 )
```

How can I achieve this?? Can anyone help me out..

Comment: Can you print your result here? with pre tag?

Comment: `$prdtarray[] = $row1->product_name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`explode` and `implode` are working as expected. The first is used to split a string and return an array with the pieces e.g.

```
 $pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
 $pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
 echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
 echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

That is why you get this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Insole Premium Shore 30 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => G Diabetic Premium closed Sandal Black size 09 ) ) when you print $prdtarray (`echo print_r($prdtarray);`). Each time you call `$prdtarray[] = explode(",", $row1->product_name);` you are creating a new array with one element (only one element because `$row1->product_name` doesn't contains any ",") and adding it to `$prdtarray`.

`implode` is used to Join array elements with a string e.g.

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
```

In your code since you have two arrays inside `$prdtarray` the result of `$product` is

```
 Array,Array
```

So, you can save the `$row1->product_name` value in an array and then use `implode` to create a comma separated values result. The code looks like this:

```
$this->db->select("product_name")
->from('sale_items')
->where('sale_items.sale_id',4221);
$q1 = $this->db->get();
if ($q1->num_rows() > 0) {
 foreach (($q1->result()) as $row1) {
$prdtarray[] = $row1->product_name;
}
$product=implode(',',$prdtarray); 
echo $product ; // Insole Premium Shore 30,G Diabetic Premium closed Sandal Black size 09
```

Comment: I tried like `$prdt.=$row1['product_name'].",";` nd it worked.. I tried as u said nd it works too.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$result = "";
foreach ($prdtarray[0] as $prdtarray_key => $prdtarray_value) {
    $result .= $prdtarray_value . ", ";
}
```

Because everything is wrapped inside element `0` of `$prdtarray` we use that element directly. Next we loop over every element and build 1 string form it by concatenating `.=` and also adding `,` (comma space) after every element we add. This will result in trailing comma space, but you can figure it out from there, right?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you .

```
$this->db->select("product_name")
    ->from('sale_items')
    ->where('sale_items.sale_id',4221);
    $q1 = $this->db->get();
    if ($q1->num_rows() > 0) {
     foreach (($q1->result_array()) as $row1) {
    $prdtarray[] = $row1['product_name'];
    }
    $product=implode(',',$prdtarray); 
    echo $product ;
```